# The Chudnovsky Formula in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, pi

I'm trying to implement the Chudnovsky algorithm for calculating pi.
I am using formulas from this description https://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-chudnovsky/

Now it's working,  but maximum number of digits it can show is
3.141592653589793238462643385 - only **27** digits.

Why does Python limits the number of digits in this script?
May be i am using **Decimal** in wrong way?

Here is my code (updated):

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
from math import factorial
import sys

def calculate_pi(max_K, number_of_digits):
    getcontext.prec = number_of_digits+2
    a_k, b_k, C, a_sum, b_sum  =  1, 0, 640320, 1, 0
    for k in range(1,max_K):
        a_k *= -(Decimal(24)/Decimal(C**3))*Decimal((6*k-5)*(2*k-1)*(6*k-1))/Decimal(k**3)
        a_sum += a_k
        b_sum += a_k*k


    pi = 426880*Decimal(10005).sqrt()/Decimal(13591409*a_sum + 545140134*b_sum)
    print str(pi)[:number_of_digits+2]

def main(number_of_digits):
    pi = calculate_pi(10000, number_of_digits)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    number_of_digits = int(sys.argv[1])
    main(number_of_digits)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `getcontext().prec = ...` instead of `getcontext.prec = ...`

Answer (score 1):

I was interested in the problem, and checked out the site you mentioned.

If you look at the definition of `a`, then you see that the first summand is `1`, and not `-6*5*4/640320^3`.
Also since you start your loop at `k = 1`, you additionally need to assign the variables `a_sum` and `b_sum` with the first summands `a_0 = 1` and `b_0 = 0`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! 
I know, but don't know where I can find help on this task(

Comment: Actually yes, stackoverflow is also (not "only", but "also") a bug-searching site. There's rules on how to ask a question exactly because people come here saying "my code doesn't work, help me out".