# Chudnovsky algorithm returns a negative and incorrect digits - Python

Tags: python, decimal, pi

I'm trying to make the Chudnovsky algorithm in Python:[image]

I'm just using the second and third parts of it (the only necessary ones). Here's my code:

```
import decimal
# sets number of digits
decimal.getcontext().prec = 100

def factorial(n):
    fact = decimal.Decimal('1')

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        fact = fact * i
    return fact

def findPi(numOfDigits):
    k = 0
    result = decimal.Decimal('0')
    next = decimal.Decimal('426880') * decimal.Decimal('10005').sqrt()
    while True:
        a = factorial(6 * k)
        b = 545140134 * k + 13591409
        # top of the chudnovsky algorithm
        top = decimal.Decimal(str(a * b))
        c = factorial(3 * k)
        d = factorial(k) ** 3
        e = -262537412640768000 ** k
        # bottom of the chudnovsky algorithm
        bottom = decimal.Decimal(str(c * d * e))
        result += top / bottom
        print(next / result)
        k += 1
findPi(50)
```

Whenever I run it, this is what it returns:
`-3.141592653589675176874263801479785514507867103418138605371738276354365851084005009510847111434082626`

It is only correct up to the twelfth digit, and the rest is incorrect (also the negative)

Comment: btw not sure you need the `Decimal(str(...))` thing.

Comment: @quamrana decimal.Decimal() only takes strings

Comment: I've seen other attempts at Chudnovsky on stack overflow also use `Decimal` with no `str(...)` in sight like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50906200/the-chudnovsky-formula-in-python)

Comment: From the docs: "*value* can be an integer, string, tuple, float, or another Decimal object". Found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#decimal.Decimal)

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad it takes those data types but if you enter a float it will store it as a float, making no difference in just storing it as a float. If you enter a string, it can store more accurate numbers because it is not storing it as a float.

Comment: Example: https://imgur.com/a/sD6oize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
e = -262537412640768000 ** k
```

to this for fixing the negative issue

```
e = (-262537412640768000) ** k
```

About the accuracy, you should first compute the sum, then do your next/result computation. You are calculating in every step of the sum. Also, you need a break statement for your while loop, you seem to not use the numOfDigits argument.